# Every time Spring MVC Controller is returning a ModelAndView Hibernate fire Selects

Tags: spring, hibernate, session, model-view-controller

I have an small web app based on Spring MVC and Hibernate. My User object have a oneToMany relationship with Pet, object:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Pet> myPets;
```

Even I am keeping my user object in Session after login (I know is a sin), and it is having his Pets included, every time a Controller method is called, after it  is returning a ModelAndView object, logs shows hibernate firing Selects.

For example

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/in_pet-see", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getSee(@RequestParam("pid") Integer pId, ModelAndView model) {
    User u = getUserFromSession();
    if(u==null) {
        u = getUser();
    }
    Set<Pet> pets = u.getMyPets();
    Pet p = getPetFromSet(pets, pId);
    model.addObject("user", u);

    model.addObject("petType", petTypeMap.get(p.getType()));
    model.addObject("petAttribute", p);
    model.setViewName("b-see-pet");
    return model;
}

private User getUserFromSession() {
    return (User)session().getAttribute("user");
}

public static HttpSession session() {
    ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
    return attr.getRequest().getSession(true); // true == allow create
}


private Pet getPetFromSet(Set<Pet> set, int pId) {
    Pet myPet = null;
    for (Iterator<Pet> it = set.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        Pet p = it.next();
        if (p.getPetId()==pId) {
            myPet = p;
        }
        System.out.println("Pet found");

    }
    return myPet;
}
```

How can I avoid that?

NOTE

My way to fix this was cloning the hibernate object and putting the clone in HttpSession, then in those methods which can make changes (rare in my app) to User or User's depending objects, at those method's end, call a synchrony method:

```
/** Get a new user from DDBB, after some change and put it on Session to deliver fresh data */
private void sinchronizeUser() {
    User oldSmith = getUserFromSession();
    User u = myUserService.loadUserById(oldSmith.getUserId());
    User smith = (User) u.clone();
    session().setAttribute("user", smith);
}
```

Comment: Without the full controller and flow this is impossible to answer. You haven't included the `getPetFromSet`. Nor is it visible if you have `@ModelAttribute` annotated methods etc. Also don't use that construct to get the `HttpSession` instead just inject it as a method parameter of type `HttpSession`.

Comment: Hi, getPetFromSet should not be important. It is just an iteration inside the set, looking for one specific id

Comment: You still haven't added the full controller nor have you explained WHICH select statement is issued. Also apparently if there is no user you do something else to obtain the user, which also makes me wonder HOW are you storing the user in the session. All in all you have an incomplete picture here which makes it impossible to answer your question.

Comment: Hi Deinum, thanks, my Controller is so long and all the important stuff are here. I finally found a way to prevent Hibernate selects and it is just cloning the Hibernate object and using the clone one in my HttpSession. Regards,

Comment: Which isn't a solution but a hack/workaround. The `User` in the `HttpSession` isn't attached to hibernate anymore, unless you are storing it on each request in the session which basically defeats the purpose of storing it in the session.

Comment: The solution is just for my case, because, each of my users have few attached objects. Changes are rare, but in the case they happen I do a synchronisation with Hibernate in each of those methods, and then clone and replace from the HttpSession the obsolete object. I am a mobile developer, really I have no time to learn Hibernate in the right way, because I am doing this just as a personal project, not for my every day working.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this behaviour is consequence of the called Hibernate dirty checking mechanism. Here you can learn more about it:

https://vladmihalcea.com/the-anatomy-of-hibernate-dirty-checking/

In my case I finally found a way to prevent Hibernate selects and it is just cloning the Hibernate object and using the clone one in my HttpSession. I mean I still using fetch eager, because I need all the user data (which is small) preloaded. And using the clone object hibernate is not firing any update.

Comment: It shouldn't do that as when it is in the session (assuming you are storing it once and not on each request) it is detached and it doesn't do dirty checking anymore.

Comment: Yes, I don't want dirty checking every time. In this way I can control when it happen.